# Is Stack Overflow hiring?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I am not looking for a job, but I'm curious about whether SO is expanding.

Is it?

Comment: "I am not looking for a job" - I call shenanigans.

Comment: **[pistol whips Eric]**

Comment: http://sanfrancisco.grubstreet.com/pistol%20whip.jpg

Comment: OK, I am truck driver and trying to make into development..there you have it

Comment: hey, i respect that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they were there would be an ad on the right =)

Comment: Or they would have just sent an email to some brilliant users.

Comment: But I don't think they'll be able to hire Jon Skeet away from his current job...

Comment: that would be useless, everyone knows the best developers all use adblock! :)

Answer (score 6):

### Yes

[waffle house http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/9408/wafflehouse.jpg](http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/9408/wafflehouse.jpg)

They are changing course to bricks mortar and ...

Answer (score 3):

No but the universe is expanding

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at the time of this writing. But that's subject to change. See https://stackoverflow.com/about/hiring for the latest updates.

Answer (score -1):

Heh, dude - if u have to ask, you're not eligable. Why do you think they created *Careers* ? So they have access to a pool of posible candidates, where they can easily pick the best and filter the crap ... on tap :)

Comment: And they're getting paid by the users to be eligible! This is the greatest scam in the history of everything.

Comment: Scam? no wai -> i think it's awesome! wish i thought of it first :)